# AttributeError: module ‘Quantlib’ has no attribute ‘NonLinearSquare’

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonlinear-optimization, quantlib

I want to implement NonLinearSquare as optimization method to solve Hull-White model calibration using CapHelper. I find there exist a class called NonLinearSquare in c++ library. But the python tells me:

```
AttributeError: module ‘Quantlib’ has no attribute ‘NonLinearSquare’
```

How could I do to use this method in python?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to `NonLinearLeastSquare`, that's not exported to Python.  You might open an issue and request it's exported, but it might be tricky to do so in a way which is useable from Python.  You're probably better off using one of the exported optimizers, such as `Simplex` or `LevenbergMarquardt`.